# center table and text in html page - vertical and horizontal

Tags: html

This should be really easy, but think dealing with brain fog.

Trying to create a page which shows text at center of the page[ vertically / horizontally]

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Application error</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>    
    </head>
    <body>
                       <table>
            <tr>

            <th style="background-color:#FFFFFF;vertical-align: central">
                 This should be center of page vertcally/horizontally
                                </th>
           </tr>
        </table>


            </body>
</html>
```

The text is aligned in center but right at top of the page - horizonatlly center but vertically.

[tried looking for tag called 'brain freeze' but could not. maybe the admins can make one for such a case]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this settings:

```
table{
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    top:50%; /* assign manually */
}
body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

jsFiddle:[here](http://jsfiddle.net/8AD4C/)

Comment: Add `margin: 0;` in your `body` to avoid the unnecessary scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wJ7dY/498/) shows how to align centerally

Make your CSS as

```
 table {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#d9d9d9;
    position:fixed;
    margin-left:-150px; /* half of width */
    margin-top:-150px;  /* half of height */
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
}
table th
{
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
```

Comment: I think, there is no need to write `vertical-align: middle;` here.

Comment: @Naveen - usally you don't can't set a fixed width and height in these cases, cause you don't know the resolution which user sits at.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `vertical-align: middle;`

Comment: (The element is aligned to middle by default, so you don't have to set `vertical-align` if you don't want to override another setting. Increase the height of the table to see the effect.)

Comment: In your original code there was `vertical-align:central` which is definately WRONG. There's no such thing as `central`. I wanted to point out this.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use tables for designing layout. Use divs instead

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;text-align:center;margin-top:50%;">
    <div style="height:20px;line-height:20px;font-size:12px;margin-top:-10px;">This should be center of page vertcally/horizontally</div>
</div>
```

Notice the `margin-top:-10px`. That is because the inner div is positioned at 50% of the outer-div. But if you really want it in the middle, you want it to positioned at 50% - "half the height of the inner div" and the height of the inner-div is 20px. The line-height makes sure that text inside the inner-div is aligned in the middle of the div.

Of course you should classes (or id's) instead:

**css:**

```
.outer {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;    //Make sure everything inside the this div is centered
    margin-top:50%;       //Position the inner-div at half of the height of this div
}

.inner {
    height:20px;         //Set a specific height
    line-height:20px;    //Set a line-height (works when only one row of text) to align text vertically in the middle
    font-size:12px;      
    margin-top:-10px;    //Position the div upwards (half the height of this div)
}
```

**html:**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div style="inner">This should be center of page vertcally/horizontally</div>
</div>
```